# Process start as different user - access is denied

Tags: c#, process.start

When I try to start a file using different user privilege on c# it's always failed on "access is denied".

```
SecureString password = new SecureString();
password.AppendChar('n');
password.AppendChar('o');
password.AppendChar('a');
password.AppendChar('m');
password.AppendChar('p');
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"\\192.1.1.34\Noam\hanal.xlsx";
process.StartInfo.Domain = "dm";
process.StartInfo.UserName = "noamp";
process.StartInfo.Password = password;
process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.Start();
```

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
> HResult=0x80004005
> Message=Access is denied.
> Source=System.Diagnostics.Process
> StackTrace:
> at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
> at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
> at DelekLinkV2.DisplayFiles.listView_DoubleClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\tomerz\Desktop\PROGRAM\DelekLinkV2\DelekLinkV2\DisplayFiles.cs:line 78
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
> at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
> at DelekLinkV2.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\tomerz\Desktop\PROGRAM\DelekLinkV2\DelekLinkV2\Program.cs:line 58

Comment: This requires what's called user impersonation. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net

Comment: Yeah something to do with login, have you created an user on 192.1.1.34?

Comment: yes, the user i used is already active .